# I want to make some sticky liquid

Tags: modeling, fluid-simulation

[image]
[image]

I want the liquid to stick to the surface of this cube, like fry batter, or rock tar.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this is pretty easy if you buy the flipFluids add-on and then use force. No, i don't get money from them, i just can recommend it because it is really good. you can check out here: https://flipfluids.com/

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust the *Viscosity* and *Diffusion* settings of the fluid domain:

[image: Physics properties showing viscosity and diffusion settings]

The drop down menu for *Diffusion* will give you some examples that you can start with, such as the honey setting:

[image: Diffusion drop down showing presets.]

Comment: Are you sure this works? Viscosity makes the liquid more viscous ... well, I mean, inert and it sticks more together. But I don't think it will stick more on a collision object, does it?

Comment: It will do part of the job, in that the liquid will flow slower.  Unlike rigid body, fluids don't have any physics changes you can make on Collision Effectors.